Why are droidekas found on Geonosis and at the Baktoid Combat Automata factory?
If droidekas or destroyer droids are made by the Colicoids on their home planet of Colla IV, why are there some on Geonosis and why are they in the factories of Baktoid Combat Automata when they were made in the Colicoid Creation Nest?


Sold to the highest bidder; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Colla_IV

Why is Jango Fett in the factory on Geonosis if he was born on Concord Dawn?

It's mentioned in a number of reference books that the Geonosians were essentially contractors for Baktoid, which was itself a part of the Techno-Union. Geonosis not being a Republic world meant that they could keep the massive military build-up relatively quiet.
So whether or not the droidekas were designed by the Colicoids is irrelevant. The Geonosians were either making them under contract from the Colicoids' specs, or Baktoid provided them to the Geonosians for security. Most likely the former.
